# Location of new-tab widget in Firefox

Tags: firefox, layout

I have two PCs both with Firefox Quantum 58.0.1 (64-bit). One of them has the bookmarks toolbar and new-tab widget in the expected places, below the address bar, and to the immediate right of the rightmost tab. The other is like this

[image: Firefox screenshot]

I guess this is a result of something such as an add-on I installed a long time ago or some other setting. I can't find any likely addons or options. I am using the default theme.

I found that I can use the ☰,"Customise" submenu to move the bookmarks toolbar content back to the normal location but I haven't found a way to move the "+" new-tab widget.

How can I make the layout the same on both PCs?

Comment: Just drug the "+" to be next to the opened tab in "Customize" mode.

Answer (score 3):

### Restore Defaults

In the end, the easiest solution was to click the "restore defaults" button at the bottom of the window opened using the ☰,"Customize" submenu.

[image: Firefox "Customize" Window]

Dragging the "+" around the "Customize" window only resulted in it snapping to the left edge, to the left of the tabs. It seemed impossible to get the "+" to stick to the right of the rightmost opened tab.

After restoring defaults, the "+" was where I wanted it and it was also then much more amenable to being relocated to a greater variety of positions.